# In PowerShell, how to get the name of a JSON object a data pair is in

Tags: json, powershell, object-graph

Given the following JSON:

```json
{
  "Team1": {
    "John Smith": {
      "position": "IT Manager",
      "employees": [
        {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "position": "Programmer"
        },
        {
          "name": "Jane Vincent",
          "position": "Developer"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Jane Smith": {
      "position": "Payroll Manager",
      "employees": [
        {
          "name": "John Bylaw",
          "position": "Clerk"
        },
        {
          "name": "Jane Tormel",
          "position": "accountant"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Team2": {
    "Bob Smith": {
      "position": "IT Manager",
      "employees": [
        {
          "name": "Bob Doe",
          "position": "Programmer"
        },
        {
          "name": "Margareth Smith",
          "position": "Developer"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Mary Smith": {
      "position": "Payroll Manager",
      "employees": [
        {
          "name": "Henry Bylaw",
          "position": "Clerk"
        },
        {
          "name": "Eric Tormel",
          "position": "accountant"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to do a search for an employee name and return the Team he/she is in and his/her manager. For example for Henry Bylaw, I want to say his manager is Mary Smith and they are on Team #2. Obviously, there are more than 2 team and more managers than this sample.

I put the JSON in a variable:

```
$jsonData = '{
    "Team1": {
        "John Smith" : {
.... Too long to post here but see above.
        }
    }   
}
```

and do this:

```
# Convert JSON string to PowerShell object
$data = $jsonData | ConvertFrom-Json

# Function to find What team is on
function FindTeam($employeeName) {
    $team1 = $data.Team1 | Where-Object { $_.employees | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $employeeName } }
    $team2 = $data.Team2 | Where-Object { $_.employees | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $employeeName } }

    if ($team1) {
        return "Team #1"
    } elseif ($team2) {
        return "Team #2"
    } else {
        return "Not found on any teams"
    }
}

# Call the function
$employeeName = "Jane Vincent"
$result = FindTeam $employeeName
Write-Output "$employeeName is on $result"
```

which results in:

```
Jane Vincent is on Not found on any teams
```

As you can see this does not work and does not scale up to hundreds of teams.
No, I cannot change the structure of the JSON.
How can I do this?

Comment: Looping through json properties is sort of a common question.  You can also take a shot at the jq `..` operator, kind of like xpath's `//`.  convertfrom-json in powershell 7 also has an -ashashtable option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really hard Json to work with, I'm unsure how to explain the logic other than pointing out that `.PSObject.Properties` can be used to reflect on the object to get its properties (the names and values).

```bash
$json = Get-Content .\test.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$target = 'Henry Bylaw'

foreach ($team in $json.PSObject.Properties) {
    foreach ($manager in $team.Value.PSObject.Properties) {
        foreach ($employee in $manager.Value.employees) {
            if ($employee.name -eq $target) {
                # `return` is used here to exit the loop,
                # if we found `$target` there is no need to keep searching
                return [pscustomobject]@{
                    Emplyee  = $employee.name
                    Position = $employee.position
                    Team     = $team.name
                    Manager  = $manager.name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output you can expect from above code is an object that has all details of that employee (`$target`):

```
Emplyee     Position Team  Manager
-------     -------- ----  -------
Henry Bylaw Clerk    Team2 Mary Smith
```

Comment: Wow, I had been laboring over this for hours. Thanks! Not sure if you're being sarcastic when you say "This is a really hard Json to work with" but it seemed pretty easy for you to come up with the solution!

Comment: @piou I'm not being sarcastic, would never be with someone asking a very valid question, the structure of this Json is really hard for someone that could be new to PowerShell. I'm glad the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) in his helpful answer Object Graphs (resulted from cmdlets along with `ConvertFrom-Json`) could be quite difficult to handle. That's why I have been busy for the last months to create some [**Object Graph Tools**](https://github.com/iRon7/ObjectGraphTools) that might ease some common use cases as this one.
To install the `ObjectGraphTools` module:

```
Install-Module -Name ObjectGraphTools
```

Underneath the cmdlets is a [`[PSNode]`](https://github.com/iRon7/ObjectGraphTools/blob/main/Docs/ObjectParser.md) class that gives you access to the nodes in the object graph. E.g. to retrieve all the
leaf nodes with the name "`name`":

```
$Object = $JsonData | ConvertFrom-Json
$NameNodes = $Object | Get-ChildNode -Recurse -Include 'Name' -Leaf
$NameNodes

PathName                              Name Depth Value
--------                              ---- ----- -----
.Team1.'John Smith'.employees[0].name name     5 John Doe
.Team1.'John Smith'.employees[1].name name     5 Jane Vincent
.Team1.'Jane Smith'.employees[0].name name     5 John Bylaw
.Team1.'Jane Smith'.employees[1].name name     5 Jane Tormel
.Team2.'Bob Smith'.employees[0].name  name     5 Bob Doe
.Team2.'Bob Smith'.employees[1].name  name     5 Margareth Smith
.Team2.'Mary Smith'.employees[0].name name     5 Henry Bylaw
.Team2.'Mary Smith'.employees[1].name name     5 Eric Tormel
```

The `PathName` property holds the path to the specific property (e.g.: `$Object.Team1.'John Smith'.employees`) in the object graph.

- Type `$EmployeeNodes | Get-Member` to show more members of the `[PSNode]` class.
- For help on the cmdlets as [`Get-ChildNode`](https://github.com/iRon7/ObjectGraphTools/blob/main/Docs/Get-ChildNode.md) type `Get-ChildNode -?` or refer to the [online documents](https://github.com/iRon7/ObjectGraphTools/tree/main/Docs).

To get the specific `$NameNode` with the value property name 'Henry Bylaw':

```
$HenryBylawNode = $NameNodes | Where-Object Value -eq 'Henry Bylaw'
$HenryBylawNode

PathName                              Name Depth Value
--------                              ---- ----- -----
.Team2.'Mary Smith'.employees[0].name name     5 Henry Bylaw
```

To get the `Position`, `Manager` and `Team`:

```
 $HenryBylawNode.ParentNode.GetChildNode('Position').Value
 Clerk     

 $HenryBylawNode.ParentNode.Parentnode.Name
 Mary Smith

 $HenryBylawNode.ParentNode.Parentnode.Parentnode.Name
 Team2
```

Putting it together:

```
$JsonData | ConvertFrom-Json |
    Get-ChildNode -Recurse -Include 'Name' -Leaf |
    Where-Object Value -eq 'Henry Bylaw' |
    ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Employee = $_.Value
            Position = $_.ParentNode.GetChildNode('Position').Value
            Team     = $_.ParentNode.ParentNode.Parentnode.Parentnode.Name
            Manager  = $_.ParentNode.ParentNode.Parentnode.Name
        }
    }

Employee    Position Team  Manager   
--------    -------- ----  -------
Henry Bylaw Clerk    Team2 Mary Smith
```

---

**Update 2024-03-08**
Based on the new published [ObjectGraphTools](https://github.com/iRon7/ObjectGraphTools) version that includes a full [Extended Dot Notation (Xdn)](https://github.com/iRon7/ObjectGraphTools/blob/main/Docs/Xdn.md) implementation, you might use the following simplified syntax:

```
$Name = 'Eric Tormel'
$Json | ConvertFrom-Json | Get-Node ~Name="$Name" | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Employee = $_.Value
        Position = $_.GetNode('....Position').Value
        Team     = $_.GetNode('.....').Name
        Manager  = $_.GetNode('....').Name
    }
}
```